# SwiftData: Migration Error: How to remove all data from Xcode?

Tags: swift-data

I'm supper new on the subject and wanted to create an app that persisted data. I have added two new attributes to the model and my app is crashing devastatingly. I'm getting this error and `ResearchResult` is an object in my model, who's child object `ResearchReference` now has two new attributes:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpected type for 
CompositeAttribute: Optional<ResearchResult>
```

What I want to do is to delete all existing data and just rested the whole thing but I can't. I now that I should probably do this, but I don't know where should I put it.

```swift
let container = try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
            
let modelContext = ModelContext(container)
try modelContext.delete(model: ResearchObject.self)
```

I'm wondering if there is a developer tool in Xcode to do this, but so far I have not found anything. Can you please guide me to what should I do?

Comment: If your target OS is iOS then try removing the app from the simulator.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson no it's actually macOS and I've tried cleaning the build folder but it persists beyond that and I have no idea where it stores the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following launch argument to the scheme you use in Xcode to run the app,

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
```

Then the path to the database file will be printed in the console right at the start when you launch the app. Something like

> "/Users/<username>/Library/Containers/<bundle identifier>/Data/Library/Application Support/default.store"

Go to that path using Finder or the Terminal app and remove the database file(s), the name is `default.store` unless you have configured it to be something else.

There might also be two other temporary files with the same name but the extensions are `.store-shm` and `.store-wal` that I also delete as well when I need to trash the database.

Then the next time you run the app SwiftData will generate new files for you.