# How to modify or update data structure using swiftData?

Tags: swift-data

Just a simple confuse how do I update my *@model* data structure after I make a container like

```
@Model
final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date
    
    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}
```

everything work fine but after add new attribute

```
@Model
final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date
    var newAtt: String

  init(timestamp: Date, newAtt: String) {
    self.timestamp = timestamp
    self.newAtt = newAtt
  }
}
```

my application can't open and get a long error(part of piece)

> error: addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error: returned error NSCocoaErrorDomain (134110) CoreData: error: addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error: returned error NSCocoaErrorDomain (134110) error: userInfo: CoreData: error: userInfo: error: sourceURL :

What's the problem with the update?

it seems I can't change data structure after setting up the container or anything wrong?

Comment: You need to perform a migration so that SwiftData knows what value to assign to existing objects. Or you supply a default value or make the property optional. Useful links https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/lightweight-vs-complex-migrations (and the following pages), https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/schemamigrationplan

Comment: A complete different solution if you not yet have any valuable data stored is to simply delete the database file, default.store, and let SwiftData generate a new one for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77335738/swiftdata-migration-error-how-to-remove-all-data-from-xcode/77337331#77337331

Comment: Thx your comments, I have followed steps but a simple issue which classes I need to use? since I replace old one. Do I need change class's name all in my code? I think tutorials not mention so much.

Comment: Did you use an enum that conforms to VersionedSchema? You do not rename the actual model class.