SwiftData failed on simulator, app showing complete black screen
I'm trying to test my app with the simulator and I have the up-to-date Xcode version. The ContentView preview works as expected, but the app shows a complete black screen on the simulator. Here's my app file
import SwiftUI

@main
struct App: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
    }
    .modelContainer(for: [A.self, B.self])
  }
}

It gives an error that SwiftData/ModelContainer.swift:144: Fatal error: failed to find a currently active container. Then I tried some solutions online like below but got the new error below. Any idea?

App.swift:19: Fatal error: Could not initialize ModelContainer error:
addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error: returned
error NSCocoaErrorDomain (134110)

import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

@main
struct App: App {
  let modelContainer: ModelContainer
  
  init() {
    do {
      self.modelContainer = try ModelContainer(for: A.self, B.self)
    } catch {
      fatalError("Could not initialize ModelContainer")
    }
  }
  
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
    }
    .modelContainer(self.modelContainer)
  }
}


Did you change any of your models (A or B) recently, could be a light migration that is failing? Maybe delete the existing database file and let SwiftData generate a new one.

Could you please suggest an approach to do it? I thought if I modify the code it uses a new container which make db to restart @JoakimDanielson

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77337331/9223839
